# Cannot resolve R.anim in adapter

Tags: java, android

When trying to call `R.anime.bounce_interpolator` in my Recycle View Adapter I keep getting an error? What's the cause?

constructor:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private List<GlobalLists> results = null;
private Context context = null;

public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<GlobalLists> results){
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.results = results;
    this.context = context;
}
```

method:

```
public void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final Animation animAnticipateOvershoot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce_interpolator);
    viewHolder.itemView.setAnimation(animAnticipateOvershoot);
}
```

Comment: you might wanna pass context to AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce_interpolator) instead of "this"

Comment: Have you defined your own `bounce_interpolator` in `res/anim/`? Or are you trying to use the system resource - `android.R.anim.bounce_interpolator`?

Comment: i doubt passing context would resolve the `bounce_interpolator`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Kelevandos its simply highlighted red

Comment: @MikeM. I'me trying to use the system resource

Comment: Then stick `android.` in front of that.

Comment: @MikeM. just did, it now compiles but I'm getting an error `Unknown animation name: bounceInterpolator`

Comment: but still progress!

Comment: Yeah, it's not an animation. It's an interpolator. It's kinda confusing that they basically call it an animation, but it's actually something that controls the speed and acceleration of animations. I didn't notice you were trying to load it as an animation. My bad.

Comment: @MikeM. ohhh that's annoying, do I have to define it myself? and what native animation libraries can I use then? Put your answer below so I can mark it correct my man

Comment: Not necessarily. You possibly are wanting one of the system animations. Just look in `android.R.anim` for anything that doesn't have `interpolator` in the name. I think there's at least `fade_in`, `fade_out`, `slide_in`-something-or-other, etc. I suppose if those aren't what you want, then you will have to define your own.